# Проблема с передачей extras из BroadcastReceiver в вызываемую Activity

Tags: android

При вызове активити через BroadcastReceiver, я передаю данные:

```
 Intent activivtyIntent = new Intent(context, MainMenuActivity.class);
 activivtyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 activivtyIntent.putExtra("OpType", intent.getStringExtra("OpType"));
 context.startActivity(activivtyIntent);
```

В MainMenuActivity в onResume  intent.getExtras()== null,  почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы запускаете уже запущенную активити, то, быть может, вам надо переопределить `onNewIntent` метод активити и в нём, из аргумента брать новый интент, в котором будет ваша информация.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть потому что intent.getStringExtra("OpType")==null

Comment: Ответ не должен быть "может быть" "а может не быть". Для коментариев есть графа коментарии, а ответ должен быть однозначным.

Comment: Даже в этом случае `intent.getExtras()` не будет равен `null`. Потому, что там лежит значение с ключём OpType, пусть даже нулевое.